# First ASM program

Tags: masm

**Hello,
I'm trying to run my first ASM 8086 program on MASM on Windows Vista 64bit OS.

I put this program on my MASM editor:**

```
.model small
.stack
.data
message   db "Hello world, I'm learning Assembly !!!", "$"

.code

main   proc
mov   ax,seg message
mov   ds,ax

mov   ah,09
lea   dx,message
int   21h

mov   ax,4c00h
int   21h
main   endp
end main
```

**and the MASM editor gives me this output that I got no idea what's wrong with the program:**

```
 Assembling: D:\masm32\First.asm
D:\masm32\First.asm(9) : error A2004: symbol type conflict
D:\masm32\First.asm(19) : warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : main
_
Assembly Error
```

**Where is the problem with this code? This is my first ASM program please remember.
Thank you :)**

Comment: Did you copy&paste your program? Looks like: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread85917.html#

Comment: Yes I did ,I'm reading a ASM Tutorial from here:
http://www.xs4all.nl/~smit/asm01001.htm

But I still got no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: @tanascius - wow, did you answer the original question 3 years ago?  Otherwise, I'm guessing you have eidetic memory.

Comment: @Kevin: lol, no - just google for *masm symbol type conflict* ^^. I was just curious, because even the message string was completely identical.

Comment: Hm , any ideas what the problem might be? :(

Comment: Just read what I linked ... or http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=8605.0 The problem seems to be always a missing 16bit linker ...

Comment: Best solution probably: look for a tutorial for 32/64bit assembler ... there seem to be plenty

Answer (score 1):

Platforms that use C a lot tend to like having an underscore before function names, depending on calling convention and executable format (hence the "with /coff switch" warning).  Try adding one to the function name?

BTW, does Vista 64-bit even support 16 bit code?  I was told it was one of the things that got dropped...see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows .

Comment: I added _ to the main function and now the Assembler writes "error 0x000182h"

I'll look up for it in Google.
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to probably install an XP virtual machine. Fire that baby up and then install [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/)
Then get yourself a copy of the 16bit linker: [16 bit linker](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/~mmacleod/masm.html)

Then try again.

Since you are using segments, you require 16 bit assembly.